# Выучить назубок

Tags: фразеология

"Выучить назубок" - значит, твердо. А при чем тут зубы или зубки? А еще интересно, что, например, "под дых" пишется раздельно, а "назубок" - слитно.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

НАЗУБОК, нареч, (разг.). Очень хорошо, наизусть. Выучить н. Знать н.

Чтобы знать что-то хорошо, надо попробовать предмет на зубок, раскусить его.

"Эта поговорка возникла из обычая проверять на зуб подлинность золотых монет, колец и других изделий из благород­ного металла. Прикусишь монету зубами, и если не осталось на ней вмятины, значит, подлинная, не поддельная. А то ведь могла попасть­ся фальшивая: полая внутри или залитая дешевым металлом".

Слитное написание наречия позволяет отличить обстоятельственное значение наречия от предметного значения существительного: на зубок - в подарок младенцу: "Подойдя к постели и подсунув карты под подушку, он прибавил: «Вот на зубок новорождённому!» (Аксаков. Семейная хроника).

"Есть в России прекрасный обычай – дарить младенцу серебряную ложку «на зубок». По традиции, если ею легонько постучать по первому, только прорезавшемуся зубу, все остальные зубки вырастут безболезненно и быстро и будут здоровыми и крепкими. Кроме того, считается, что серебряная ложечка на первый зуб призвана привлечь в жизнь маленького человечка богатство и успех во всех начинаниях".http://silver1.ru/magazin/folder/pervyy-zub

Раздельное написание "под дых" (под дыхательный центр) связано с наличием падежного управления: подо что? В этом случае различать предметное и обстоятельственное значения нет необходимости.

Comment: Есть  ещё  выражение: выучить  так,  чтоб  от  зубов  отскакивало.

Comment: Мне в детстве подарили серебряную ложечку, но что-то ни богатства, ни здоровых зубов...)))))))

Comment: Я  думаю,  что  выражение  пробовать  на  зуб  и  выучить  назубок  не  связаны.  У  каждого  должна  быть  своя  этимология.  И  у  выражения  подарить  на  зубок - своя.

Comment: Скорее всего, выражения "пробовать на зуб" и "выучить назубок" связаны, только связь не совсем очевидная. Возможно, выучить назубок - это выучить с расчетом на последующую проверку. А у выражений пробовать на зуб, подарить на зубок - значение прямое, как и орфография (управление падежом).

Answer (score 1):

Есть ещё одна схожая поговорка: "выучить так, чтобы от зубов отскакивало". При таком знании ответы будут уверенные и чёткие, отскакивающие от зубов. Плохо знающий человек, говорит сквозь зубы, глотает звуки, мямлит, старается, чтобы его слова были нерасслышаны. На мой взгляд, "назубок" - просто сокращённая фраза, трансформированная в наречие, кстати, именно поэтому это слово и пишется слитно. В то время, как слово "под дых", никто пока к наречиям не причислил, хотя оно и отвечает на вопрос: куда? Но вы можете это сделать, почему бы и нет?

Comment: В русской орфографии форма написания слов  связана с их грамматикой и смыслом, поэтому никто и никуда слова не зачисляет. Знать назубок и подарить на зубок - это обычная пара существительное-наречие, каких у нас много (держать в тайне - надеяться втайне, идти навстречу - надеяться на встречу). И "под дых" в наречия переводить не будут, у нас много подобных выражений с раздельным написанием и падежным управлением (без ведома, до упаду, с лихвой).

Comment: София, вы не задумывались, кто создавал законы грамматики? Боги, люди, такие, как вы, я,cat, или они сами себя создают?

Comment: Язык - живая материя, ее создают люди, пользователи данного языка. Ученые-лингвисты изучают его природу, анализируют ГРАММАТИЧЕСКИЙ строй, определяют закономерность построения речевых отрезков (слов, предложений). Весь этот материал формулируется в виде грамматических правил. ОРФОГРАФИЯ как наука в большей степени субъективна, чем грамматика, ей всего-то около 300 лет. Еще в начале 20 века ученые спорили о том, какие принципы должны лежать в ее основе. Именно тогда ведущим принципом был назван морфологический, который действует и до сегодняшнего дня. Вои и наречие "назубок" ему соответствует.